# Should I delete QSensorReading after using it?

Tags: memory-management, qt5, sensors

I am trying to use `QSensor` and friends in `Qt5.5` for the first time, and a question has come up; **who is responsible for managing instances of** `QSensorReading`? I have tried to understand this by reading the documentation without getting any wiser.

**Example:**

```
QAccelerometer *accelerometer=new QAccelerometer(this);
if(accelerometer->connectToBackend()){
    accelerometer->start();
}

//Some time later in handler for QSensorReading::readingChanged()signal:
QAccelerometerReading *myReading=accelerometer->reading();
```

What can I do with `myReading` here? Should I delete it? Will it be automaticaly delted? Can I pass it safely along as a parameter? Do I risk it being updated (mutable)? Can I copy it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's owned by the `QSensorBackend`, so it'll be deleted with it. The pointer can be passed, but the object doesn't look like copyable. The value inside may be updated (but it's thread safe if it's used in the same thread where the backend lives). The pointer stays the same.